# Not getting all JSON data from URL

Tags: python, json, urllib

i am using this code to get some data from JSON from this URL:
https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/

And i am using this code for that, **but i am not getting all results ( all countries) i dont know why !!** :

```
import json
import urllib.request

# Print Daily Updated Report from JSON file in this (URL)

url = "https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

obj = json.loads(data)
for p in obj['records']:
        print('Country: ' + p['countriesAndTerritories'])
        print('Date: ' + p['dateRep'])
        print('Cases: ' + str(p['cases']))
        print('Deaths: ' + str(p['deaths']))
        print('')
```

There was an error but i solve it but the problem not solved yet !. I just add this before my code to solve the error:

```
import json
import urllib.request
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context



# Print Daily Updated Report from JSON file in this (URL)

url = "https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

obj = json.loads(data)
for p in obj['records']:
        print('Country: ' + p['countriesAndTerritories'])
        print('Date: ' + p['dateRep'])
        print('Cases: ' + str(p['cases']))
        print('Deaths: ' + str(p['deaths']))
        print('')
```

Comment: Why do you think you aren't getting all the data?  Even using your first query, I'm getting 9600 lines of output, which is everything.

Comment: There are 1920 objects on the website. and the code fetches all of them. what's the problem?

Comment: @AvenDesta i tried this code on Vs code but i am getting only from Sweden,Spain and Slovenia. But when i run the code in Replit and stop it before its end i see all countries. If i didn't stop running the code i get the same result like vs code !